# How to distribute the cost of a journey among passengers (read)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

Difficult to title this post, i'll try to articulate the problem as best as possible.

I'm building a program that should distribute the cost of a journey where nodes are being dropped off in a particular order.

First it declares the `order` in which the destination nodes are visited (does not include origin) [2,1]
Next, the distances of the `legs` are declared. In this case, the journey legs are 1000 and 500. Thus, it takes 1000 metres to travel from origin->2 and 500 metres to travel from 2->1. Then the program builds an associative array `fares` of destinations => price that should be paid (set to 0 for now)

I am now struggling with using a for loop to add the appropriate values to the fares array. I need a way of **equitably** distributing the cost to the appropriate nodes;

In this case, Node 2 would pay half of the first leg (500).

Node 1 would pay half of the first leg (500) and bare the full price of the second leg (500) = 1000 overall.

I've been trying to work out how to solve this problem but struggling, any suggestions are appreciated. P.S: The program should be able to handle more than 2 nodes/legs.

Current code: https://jsfiddle.net/hotkeying/uub9g972/3/

```
//order of destinations
order = [2,1]
fares = {}
price = 15
total = 1500;
PricePerMetre = price/total
legs = [1000, 500]
//builds the associative array
for (i=0; i<Order.length; i++){
                fares[Order[i]]=0;              
    }

//not working
for (i=0; i < Order.length; i++){
    fares[Order[i]] = legs[i]/Order.length * PricePerMetre
  console.log(fares);

}
```

Comment: Dude, you have a typo in your fiddle at line 16 - `legs[0]`. Change it to `legs[i]` and your algorythm starts working

Comment: No it doesn't, that returns Object {1: 2.5, 2: 5} when it should be Object {1: 10, 2: 5}

Comment: it returns `{1: 5, 2: 2.5}` which is almost the value you want, fix coefficients and thats it